# Do I get more XP in PvP matches?

Tags: paragon

In Paragon, do I get more experience points if I play against real people, as opposed to laying against AI controlled opponent?

In Overwatch for example, you certainly earn more experience after the match if you play against real players. I'm wondering if the same is true for Paragon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive full rewards (including xp) if you play PvE (Play with other people against bots), however you don't receive anything if you play solo against bots anymore.

Those changes were introduced in an update 3-4 months ago.